# Which theorem is used here?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is not invertible, then since the polynomial $\det(A+xI_n)$ has finitely many zeros, $A + xI_n$ is invertible for any sufficiently small $x > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (squared) matrix $B$ is invertible if and only if $\det(B)\ne 0$.

Indeed, $\det(A+xI_n)=0$ only for finitely many values of $x$, namely, $\{x_1,\cdots,x_p\}$ with $p\le n$.

Let $x_0:= \min\{x_j:\, x_j\ne0\}$ (if $x_j\le0$ for all $j$, then take $x_0$ to be any positive real number). Then it is clear that for any $0<x<x_0$, $\det(A+xI_n)\ne0$ and your matrix is invertible.

Comment: Why does $det(A+xI_n)$ have at most n zeroes?

Comment: Thanks @Rzu. I used in the correct form at the bottom of the answer....

Comment: @RayOfHope Because $det(A+xI_n)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. So apply (as @Rzu) says) the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: What if $\lbrace x_j \rbrace$ contains both positive and negative number?

Comment: Take  The mínimum of The poeitive Ones